# "base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type" But It is pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, stl, std-pair

This is my code.(I simplified this,Normally there were a lot of member functions,but error still same,So I simplified it.)

```
template <class K,class V>
class MyMap:public MySet<pair<K, V> >{};

int main(void){

    MyMap<int,int> map1;

    MyMap<int,int>::MyIterator it;

    it=map1.begin();

    cout<<it->first<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the type is just `MyIterator`, not a pointer.

Comment: +1 for creating a (relatively) minimal test case that actually reproduces the issue (so rare in questions nowadays :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth unfortunately you were too fast with praising the example. After the edit it isnt complete anymore

Comment: It is not clear what your question is, perhaps it was clear before the edit, but not any longer.

Comment: Please revert your edit.  The question was answerable without it, but not with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide the `->` operator to `MyIterator` class, something as this:

```
T *operator->() {
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I worked it on 2-3 hours.

Comment: @EasterGamer You're welcome. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer. If another problem appears, please start a new question.

Comment: @EasterGamer, after you’ll make it complete, I recommend [CodeReview.se] to make it better.